# How to move between different tabs with Next button in Visual Studio with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution.  I am hoping to have a button that has code that is something like this.  Anyone know how to make this happen?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click()

 Dim TabPosition as int

 TabPosition = Tabcontrol1.SelectedTab.Value

       if TabPosition = 1

 Then TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2

       ElseIf TabPosition = 2

 Then TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage3

 End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SelectedIndex property to know your position:

```
If TabControl1.SelectedIndex = TabControl1.TabCount - 1 Then
  TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(0)
Else
  TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(TabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1)
End If
```